# Django Many to Many friends relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I'm experimenting with Django and I'm trying to figure out how to define a many to many relationship relating one entity to itself. Let's say, for eg., I have a custom user object called "Myuser". I want Myuser to have a list of friends that are also of type Myuser:

```
class Myuser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_login = DateTimeField(blank=True)
    is_active  = BooleanField(default=True)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(Myuser)
    objects = MyuserManager()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Myuser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.myuser = self


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.user.is_authenticated()
```

That won't work because Myuser is not defined at the friends scope. So how would I define such a relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has a special syntax for Many-to-many fields from a model to itself.

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), you would want to use something like this in your model:

```
friends = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

In general, Django doesn't have a problem with defining fields to models that are out of scope, or which haven't been defined yet. The solution is to name the model with a string, and that name is resolved once the other model has been defined. This is necessary when defining two models that have foreign keys to one another, for instance. `'self'` is a special case, though, for relationships back to the model which you are currently defining.

Comment: Are there any online tutorials or documentation explaining how to properly set up such a relationship? I am able to syncdb using the special "self" value, but when I attempt to load my custom user in the admin view I get errors: "relation "myuser_myuser_friends" does not exist
LINE 1: ...yuser"."name" FROM "myuser_myuser" INNER JOIN "myuser_..."

Comment: Post your model, and your admin classes, and I'm sure I'll (or someone else here will) be able to help out. If you got syncdb working, you're almost certainly almost all the way there.

Comment: I don't know if it's working as expected. The model is as above. After running syncdb I don't seem to get "myuser_myuser_friends" added to my db schema. In debug and crash when the application attempts to execute this SQL: "SELECT "myuser_myuser"."id", "myuser_myuser"."user_id", "myuser_myuser"."username", "myuser_myuser"."last_login", "myuser_myuser"."is_active", "myuser_myuser"."birthday", "myuser_myuser"."name" FROM "myuser_myuser" INNER JOIN "myuser_myuser_friends" ON ("myuser_myuser"."id" = "myuser_myuser_friends"."to_myuser_id") WHERE "myuser_myuser_friends"."from_myuser_id" = 32
"

Comment: I finally figured out my problem. I didn't realize that syncdb does not add fields to an existing schema. I had to remove my tables and re-create them with syncdb. Thanx, your tip helped!